# How to drag down a BottomSheet view from inside a NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, android-scrollview, bottom-sheet, android-nestedscrollview, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have inside my **BottomSheet** view a **NestedScrollView** and I want to drag down the `bottomSheet` when scrolling down from the `nestedScrollview` but it is not working.

My XML code is like below :

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="230dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

     <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/window_background"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
     
           ...

      </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

      <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">  

           ...

      </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>    
 
    
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Try to disable the nested scrolling of the `NestedScrollView`

Comment: @Zain But I needed for the inside scroll also !

Comment: @Zain Strange like suggestion but I tried it and it is not working

Comment: But I think when the NSV scrolls to the top; you'll be able to drag down the BottomSheet right?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not dragging down the `BottomSheet` that the nested scrolling  of the `NestedScrollView` is enabled which catches the scrolling event until scrolling all the way up.

Disabling the `NestedScrollView` is not an option because it's needed in bottom scrolling. And intermittent enabling/disabling of it can cause unexpected scrolling behavior.

**Workaround:** An option to solve this; is to scroll all the way up whenever the `NestedScrollView` detects an up scroll, so that the bottom sheet can take the chance of collapsing:

```
// Kotlin 
nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener { _, _, scrollY, _, oldScrollY ->
    if (scrollY < oldScrollY) // Scroll up
        nestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, 0)
})

// Java
nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView nestedScrollView, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
        if (scrollY < oldScrollY) // Scroll up
            nestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
});
```

The down side that the user would see the top content of the `NestedScrollView` before it goes off; or even if they changed their mind of not collapsing the bottom sheet. Probably not the best option; but it is simple and works.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but it is not working, it has no effects

Comment: I tried it in a bare-bone project and worked.. Probably you have much more in yours